# java.net.UnknownHostException on file:// method

Tags: java, exception, url

```
failed to open file file://D/:/dev/test_all.html  JavaException: java.net.UnknownHostException: D
```

Any ideas for why this happens?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

the third / is in the wrong place, the file url is contructed with `file:///<path>`

Comment: Adding an extra slash in front of the path fixed the problem. Apparently, file:///D/:/dev/test_all.html is considered legal.

Comment: As mentioned in www.coderanch.com/t/185526/java-developer-SCJD/certification/UnknownHostException. The format is protocol://hostname/file and since the host name is empty you end up with three slashes (protocol:///file).

Comment: Simply placing the current directory file name didn't resolve correctly. Is that platform based Java bug?

Comment: Path are resolved based on the directory where your application did start from. So it depends a bit where you started the application and what file indication you used. But that is worth a seperate question

Answer (score 6):

Your URL is malformed.  Instead of `file://D/:/` you want `file://D:/` -- no slash between the drive letter and the colon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution that's actually working with XMLParserv2, I hope this helps:

```
protected URL createURL(String filename){

        URL url = null;

        try {
            url = new URL("file://" + System.getProperty("user.dir") +  File.separator + filename);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return url;
    }
```